# On two nested radicals and divisibility

Tags: divisibility, radicals, nested-radicals

The last days I was playing around with two nested radicals which, as I learned here, can be simplified:
$$u(x) =\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x +\sqrt{x +\sqrt{x +...}}}} = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1+4x})$$
$$l(x) = \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x -\sqrt{x -\sqrt{x -...}}}} = \frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{1+4x})$$

Whilst doing so I noticed something cool (maybe completely trivial or obvious but *I* think it's cool):

$u(x)$ and $l(x)$ are integers whenever $x = u(x)*l(x)$, where $u(x) = l(x)+1$. 
I.e. when $x = k(k+1)$, e.g. $6, 12, 20, 30,\dots$
This can be generalized for  $x = k(k+n)$:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1+4(x+(\frac{n^2-1}{4}))}\pm n)$$
[image: Graph of u and l]

My question: Is it possible to create a set of similiar functions $\{f_1(x),\dots,f_p(x)\}$, with the corresponding x-value being the product of their values, basicly extending the concept to higher roots? I.e:
$$x = \prod^{p}_{k=1}{f_k(x)}$$

Comment: I'm confused; $x$ is *always* the product of $u$ and $l$. You can verify this by just multiplying the expressions on the right. So it seems like what you're asking just boils down to when $\sqrt{1+4x}$ is an odd integer

Comment: I think TomGrubb is right in that the property of $u_n$, $l_n$ should not be that they are integers iff $x=u_n(x)l_n(x)$. This is true for any $x$, also when $u$ and $l$ are not integers. I think what you want is $u_n(x)\in \mathbb Z \iff l_n(x)\in \mathbb Z \iff x=k(k+n)$ for some integer $k$. (This might be what you already meant).

Comment: Yes you are both correct, thanks. I removed the uneccesarry condition.